# Iterate over items within an object

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to parse through the json output of one of our es clusters to collect filter cache stats and was hoping to use Jq to do it. Here is the output from the `curl` command:

```
{
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5662,
    "successful": 5662,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "_all": {
    "primaries": {
      "filter_cache": {
        "memory_size": "32.8gb",
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 35245081088,
        "evictions": 31347095
      }
    },
    "total": {
      "filter_cache": {
        "memory_size": "94.3gb",
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 101307321504,
        "evictions": 79329152
      }
    }
  },
  "indices": {
    "oreserverdk04180047": {
      "primaries": {
        "filter_cache": {
          "memory_size": "0b",
          "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
          "evictions": 11
        }
      },
      "total": {
        "filter_cache": {
          "memory_size": "0b",
          "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
          "evictions": 132
        }
      }
    },
    "janbe10200002": {
      "primaries": {
        "filter_cache": {
          "memory_size": "0b",
          "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
          "evictions": 88
        }
      },
      "total": {
        "filter_cache": {
          "memory_size": "0b",
          "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
          "evictions": 119
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically I would like to get the output to look something like this:

```
oreserverdk04180047 0b
janbe10200002 0b
```

I just want the name of the index and the memory_size column from "total". I can get it if I run this through hardcoding the index names as such:

```
jq '. | {memory_size: .indices.janbe10200002.total.filter_cache.memory_size}'
```

But I was hoping to iterate through using some sort of wild card for the index name.

Answer (score 1):

```
jq -r  '
  .indices
  | to_entries[]
  | "\(.key) \(.value.total.filter_cache.memory_size)"
' input.json
```

Output:

```
oreserverdk04180047 0b
janbe10200002 0b
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that uses **foreach**

```
  .indices
| foreach keys[] as $k (
      .
    ; .
    ; "\($k) \(.[$k].total.filter_cache.memory_size)"
  )
```

EDIT: I now realize a filter of the form `foreach E as $X (.; .; R)` can almost always be rewritten as `E as $X | R` so the above is really just

```
  .indices
| keys[] as $k
| "\($k) \(.[$k].total.filter_cache.memory_size)"
```